# Returning rows from a specific column name from a DataTable - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I've been trying to find an answer online but I'm working with a DataTable and I want to filter all rows based on the column name in the table but I can't seem to get the filterExpression to work. Even though the syntax is wrong, this is basically what I want it to do....

DataRow[] row = sqlDT.Select(ColumnName = "Foo", "ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

Thanks so much.

Comment: what code have you currently got? what error or problems is it giving? just saying this syntax is wrong but is roughly what iw ant it to do doesnt help us atall :S

Comment: I really don't have much code it was more of a question of "how would you go about doing this". I have a DataTable and I want to filter values from a specific column (whose name I will pass into the method), and then return an object of those values from the column. I was checking out the Select() method for the DataTable class and was wondering if/how I could compare the column name and ONLY return rows for that column....similar to a SQL statement of SELECT * FROM "ColumnName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. I would suggest using LINQ to filter the rows:

```
sqlDT = sqlDT.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ColumnName") == "Foo").CopyToDataTable();
```

You can also use the `Select` method or the `DefaultView.RowFilter` property:

```
//select method
sqlDT = sqlDT.Select("ColumnName = 'Foo'").CopyToDataTable();

//row filter property
sqlDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ColumnName = 'Foo'";
sqlDT = sqlDT.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

**EDIT**

If you just want to filter out unneeded columns, use the `DefaultView.ToTable()` method:

```
sqlDT = sqlDT.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...does it recognize "ColumnName" as a property? or were you referring to the name of the column from my table?

Comment: No, I was referring to the name of the column from your table. Replace `ColumnName` with whatever column you want to filter against.

Comment: So I wanted to filter by the column, so I'm not sure that would work right?...similar to a SQL statement of SELECT "ColumnName" FROM "TableName" only from my DataTable.

Comment: All of the examples above are filtering by the column. Where is the disconnect, because I tried to stay close to the example code you provided.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the table to contain only the columns you're selecting?

Comment: I just updated my answer - is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I understand what you are saying in your examples but VS doesn't like the way in which I want to write it. I'd end up filtering it as ColumnName = ColumnName (because the name of the column I want to filter would be passed into the method where this code would run). I guess I don't understand why this needs to be a string that evaluates as a boolean and instead specify just a name of a DataColumn and it returns all the rows for that column. I guess that's the disconnect.

Comment: See the last example in my answer. I think that's what you're looking for. Initially, I thought you wanted to filter the rows by the value in a certain column, but it sounds like you just want to retrieve a subset of the data. My last example should do what you're looking for.

Comment: ya my fault for not explaining it well. worked, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong order,simply do it like this:
Datatable.rows(0//its count).item("column name");
You could loop it then with foreach and make a list

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this

DataRow[] row = sqlDT.Select("ColumnName =' " + Foo + " ' " , "ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

I hope this work for you.